# Problems Decrypt with nodejs crypto module

Tags: node.js, cryptography

Node.js Version: 11.13.0
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (Codename: bionic)

I try to use crypto to encrypt data with a public key from file system, using padding RSA_PKCS1_PADDING.
It works well, but I can't decrypt the result with a private key from filesytem, using the same padding.

Below, my test function

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');
var crt = crypto.createPrivateKey(fs.readFileSync(curPath + '/openssl/clinaccess.key.pem'));
 var keyProfile = crypto.createPublicKey(fs.readFileSync(curPath + '/openssl/merqurio_clinaccess_new.pub'));

exports.Crypt = function (req, res, next) {
    var data = req.param('data', '');

    if(data.length > 0){        

        var bufferEn = Buffer.from(data);
        var msg = crypto.publicEncrypt({ key: keyProfile, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING }, bufferEn).toString('base64');

        var bufferDe = Buffer.from(msg, 'base64');
        var dec = crypto.privateDecrypt({ key: crt, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING }, bufferDe).toString('utf8');

        res.end(dec);
      }
      else{
        res.status(401).end('Not authorized...');
    }
}
```

I expected to obtain original data, but I have following error:

error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong key: the public key and private key you are using are not a pair.